# Why are eigenvectors produced by np.linalg.eig different than the PCA components stored in the instance of the PCA object?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, pca

I am trying to understand why `eVec` (produced by `np.linalg.eig`) is different than `pca.components_.T` from the instance of the PCA class.  It was my understanding that the eigenvecters of the covariance matrix *are* the principal components after descending sort by eigenvalues.

An explanation in simple terms would be appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

df = pd.read_csv(
'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/seankross/a412dfbd88b3db70b74b/raw/5f23f993cd87c283ce766e7ac6b329ee7cc2e1d1/mtcars.csv'
)

df = df.drop(['model', 'vs', 'am'], axis = 1)

df = df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x))

M = df.to_numpy()

Mnorm = M-np.mean(M, axis=0)

Mnorm = Mnorm/np.std(M, axis=0)
#  This is the normalized source data.

C = (Mnorm.T @ Mnorm) / (Mnorm.shape[0] - 1)
#  This is the Covariance Matrix without bias.

eVal1, eVec1 = np.linalg.eig(C)

eVal = eVal1[np.flip(np.argsort(eVal1))]
#  eVal is sorted according to the order of the eigenvalues.

eVec = eVec1[np.flip(np.argsort(eVal1))]
#  The same sort order as above is applied to the eigenvectors.

### From sklearn:

scaler = StandardScaler()

scaler = scaler.fit(df.to_numpy())

Anorm = scaler.transform(df.to_numpy())   

pca = PCA(n_components=9)

pca_transform = pca.fit_transform(Anorm)

assert (Mnorm == Anorm).all().all()
#  This tests that Mnorm was probably constructed correctly.

assert (C.round(10) == pca.get_covariance().round(10)).all().all()
#  This indicates that the Covariance Matrix (C) was constructed correctly - the rounding is arbitrary.

assert (eVec.round(5) == pca.components_.T.round(5)).all().all()
#  However, eVec and pca.components_.T are not equal.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems:

1. Your sorting is incorrect:

```py
eVec = eVec1[np.flip(np.argsort(eVal1))]
```

sorts the *rows* of the matrix, but you want to sort the columns.  Replacing this with

```py
eVec = eVec1[:, np.flip(np.argsort(eVal1))]
```

fixes this issue.

2. The sign of the eigenvectors are sometimes opposite.  (That's fine, being an eigenvector is scale invariant, and while both `np.linalg` and `sklearn` use unit eigenvectors, that still leaves a choice of two.  I'm not sure how the packages end up picking one.)